# facebook shares/likes over a time period

Tags: facebook, time, facebook-like, share, period

How can I get the number of FB shares/likes for some FB object over a time period?

For example, I'd like to get how many shares where for some url from January, 1st, 2011 until January, 30th, 2011.

Answer (score 0):

There is the link_stat table:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/
but I don`t think there is any timestamp there, or anywhere in the facebook database.
What you can do is query this table and save the stats in your DB at the beginning and end of the period, and compare the values.

Comment: You can also try using the insights table: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/ It exists for a limited number of objects, but might include what you need.

Comment: adding to this, insights never really shows the number per day but shows you the number gained or lost per day for certain objects. So work backwards to get specific values. E.g. Take todays number then subtract each gain backwards to get the value on a specific date.